# Front page not loading after updating PHP version (ec2)

Tags: php

I first updated my PHP version from 5.3 to 5.6 and then to 7. Everything seems to work fine except for 2 things. Both on 5.6 and 7.

The front page won't load (!) and the custom css from the Simple Custom CSS plugin isn't being applied to any of the other pages.

I get a status 200 code when I load the front page but nothing happens.

The only error in the debug log is this: 
 PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php on line 6331

Also I can't load my info.php file, it results in a page not found error.

I'm using a LAMP server on AWS EC2.

PHP v7
apache v2.4.23
Mysql v5.5.52

Maybe I'm missing a PHP module?

These are the activated modules:

bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
imagick
json
libxml
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zlib

Or do I need to change a setting in my httpd.conf file? I changed allowoverride to all.
Also deleting my .htaccess file doesn't seem to fix it so I don't think that's causing it?

I don't really know what I'm doing so I'd appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it! The front page was loading index.html instead of index.php. 
I added "DirectoryIndex index.php index.html" to the .htaccess and that fixed it.
Also fixed the custom css.